# How to detect horizontal scrolling in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

How do I detect horizontal scrolling with jQuery?

This will get all scrolls:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    alert('in');
});
```

I want just the horizontal one.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
var lastScrollLeft = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var documentScrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
    if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
        console.log('scroll x');
        lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft;
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4qmz/).

Comment: Why do we need the .scroll(); at the end?

Comment: @Aharon That was the appendix of my previous incarnation. It is unnecessary now and I will update my answer :)

Comment: This only increments the value. How i can increment it when going right and decrement it when going left do you know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved it! [link](http://forrst.com/posts/jQuery_Determine_Scroll_Direction-LLJ). For horizontal only change .scrollTop() for .scrollLeft() and ready to go! Hope helps somebody.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I detect end of the scrolling in a div. Like we can detect that user reach to the bottom end of the scrolling using scrollTop and scrollHeight but how to detect same in horizontal?

Comment: @JayShukla `scrollLeft` and `scrollWidth` I would guess.

Answer (score 7):

An update that shows direction left or right in a horizontal scroll based on code above:

```
var lastPos = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currPos = $(document).scrollLeft();

    if (lastPos < currPos) {
        console.log('scroll right');
    } 
    if (lastPos > currPos) 
    {
        console.log('scroll left');
    }

    lastPos = currPos;
});
```

Test it at
http://jsfiddle.net/EsPk7/7/

Answer (score 4):

dunderwood's jsFiddle link didn't actually contain his code. I've forked his jsFiddle with what a mixture of what he posted here and what's on the jsFiddle:

```
var lastPos = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currPos = $(document).scrollLeft();

    if (lastPos < currPos) {
        $('#current').html('Right');
    }
    if (lastPos > currPos) {
        $('#current').html('Left');
    }

    lastPos = currPos;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kuVK8/

Comment: There is have a little problem. When you go up/or down, writing right and left. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onresize = function() { 
    if ( $("div").outerWidth() < $("div").get(0).scrollWidth ) {
        console.log("foo bar scrollbar");
    } else {
        console.log(" no scrolling ");
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer as to why this solves the issue? A good answer on SO always has an explanation behind it.