# Is there a way to detect horizontal scroll only without triggering a browser reflow

Tags: javascript, html, reflow

You can detect a browser scroll event on an arbitrary element with:

```
element.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    // do something
});
```

I would like to be able to differentiate between vertical scrolling and horizontal scrolling and execute actions for them independently.

I'm currently doing this by stashing the values of element.scrollTop, and element.scrollLeft, and then comparing them inside the event listener.  E.g.

```
var scrollLeft, scrollTop;
element.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (scrollLeft !== element.scrollLeft) {
        // horizontally scrolled

        scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft;
    }

    if (scrollTop !== element.scrollTop) {
        // vertically scrolled

        scrollTop = element.scrollTop;
    }
});
```

This works fine, however from https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a I read that reading the scrollLeft or scrollTop values causes a reflow.

Is there a better way to do this without causing a browser reflow on scroll?

Comment: Track your element's `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` values, and see if they changed when you handle a scroll event, updating them at the end of the handling so they're ready for the next event handling?

Comment: If you didn't change the DOM structure between your events, it won't trigger a reflow, or more exactly, the reflow will have nothing to do. Nelson is right, you should anyway throttle scroll events, but it's not because of the reflow, but simply because it makes little sense to react faster than screen refresh rate to this "*graphical*" event.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think your code is right, because at the end of the day you need to read one of those properties to find out the scroll direction, but the *key thing* here to avoid performance problems is to **throttle the event**, because otherwise the `scroll` event fires too often and that is the root cause for performance problems.

So your example code adapted to throttle the `scroll` event would be like this:

```
var ticking = false;
var lastScrollLeft = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (!ticking) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {

            var documentScrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
            if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
                console.log('scroll x');
                lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft;
            }

            ticking = false;
        });
        ticking = true;
    }
});
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll#Example

Comment: Yes it's good to use rAF to throttle this event, might even be better to use passive events in case you don't want to `preventDefault` the event.

Answer (score 7):

Elements that use `position: absolute;` are taken out of the document flow [(see source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning).

With this in mind, you could use CSS to make your `element` absolutely-positioned within its parent...

```
#parent{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px; 
    // ...or whatever dimensions you need the scroll area to be
    position: relative;
}
#element{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

... and then you can feel free to read the `element.scrollLeft` and `element.scrollTop` attributes as you did in your original question without fear of bottlenecks from reflowing the entire DOM.

This approach is also [recommended in Google's developer guidelines](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow#guidelines).

Comment: very good answer thank you... this simple trick can improve the performance by so much when finding out the top/left property using getBoundingClientRect for stuff like parallax scrolling

Answer (score 6):

What about listening to the input directly?

```
element.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
    if ( e.deltaX !== 0 ) {
        horizontal();
    }
    if ( e.deltaY !== 0 ) {
        vertical();
    }
})
```

You also might need to create your own scrollbars and listen for dragging on them. It's reinventing the wheel (lol) but hey there's no `scrollTop` or `scrollLeft` in sight.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for mouse-wheel only.
Dragging scrolling bar horizontally does not reach this code as the DOM emitted event is different.

Comment: This is perfect answer if we just replace 'wheel' with 'scroll' because for wheel it won't listen for touch scroll and scrollbar dragging by mouse

Comment: There’s no deltaX or deltaY on a scroll event

Answer (score 1):

Try **[fast-dom](https://github.com/wilsonpage/fastdom)** library:

Run [the example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlvw7k1p14) on your side locally to get correct profiling data.

```
import fastdom from 'fastdom'

let scrollLeft
let scrollTop
const fast = document.getElementById(`fast-dom`)

fast.addEventListener(`scroll`, function fastDom() {
  fastdom.measure(() => {
    if (scrollLeft !== fast.scrollLeft) {
      scrollLeft = fast.scrollLeft
      console.log(scrollLeft)
    }
    if (scrollTop !== fast.scrollTop) {
      scrollTop = fast.scrollTop
      console.log(scrollTop)
    }
  })
})
```

[image]

[image: Edit fast-dom eaxmple]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Browser_compatibility)

There's a [w3c polyfill](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill) available since [native support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver) isn't widespread enough.

The polyfill debounces scroll events

Answer (score 0):

As said in @Nelson's answer, there is **no way** to check between horizontal and vertical scroll, and the reason is because the triggered event object has zero information about it (I just checked it).

Mozilla has [a bunch of examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize#Examples) of how to throttle the element property check, but I personally prefer the `setTimeout` approach, because you can fine-tune the FPS response to match your needs. With that in mind, I wrote this read-to-use example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <style>
  #foo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  #baz {
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="foo">
    <div id="baz"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    // Using ES5 syntax, with ES6 classes would be easier.
    function WaitedScroll(elem, framesPerSecond, onHorz, onVert) {
      this.isWaiting = false;
      this.prevLeft = 0;
      this.prevTop = 0;
      var _this = this;

      elem.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        if (!_this.isWaiting) {
          _this.isWaiting = true;
          setTimeout(function() {
            _this.isWaiting = false;
            var curLeft = elem.scrollLeft;
            if (_this.prevLeft !== curLeft) {
              _this.prevLeft = curLeft;
              if (onHorz) onHorz();
            }
            var curTop = elem.scrollTop;
            if (_this.prevTop !== curTop) {
              _this.prevTop = curTop;
              if (onVert) onVert();
            }
          }, 1000 / framesPerSecond);
        }
      });
    }

    // Usage with your callbacks:
    var waiter = new WaitedScroll(
      document.getElementById('foo'), // target object to watch
      15, // frames per second response
      function() { // horizontal scroll callback
        console.log('horz');
      },
      function() { // vertical scroll callback
        console.log('veeeeeeeertical');
      }
    );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been investing and I come up with this solution:

I had to change a css property to two elements when scrolling horizontally. Hope it helps to anyone anyone who wants to control this aspect. Cheers!

```
var lastScrollLeft= 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var position= $(document).scrollLeft();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    if(position == 0){
            $("#top_box, #helper").css("position","fixed");
    }else if(position !== lastScrollLeft){
            $("#top_box, #helper").css("position","absolute");
            lastScrollLeft= position;
    }
    })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave only the horizontal scroll event in the following way.

```js
const target = document.querySelector('.target');

function eventWheelHorizontal(e) {
  // Horizontal
  if (e.deltaX != '-0') {
    e.preventDefault();
    // working
  }
}

target.addEventListener('wheel', eventWheelHorizontal, { passive: false });
```

You can share events by applying this simple method.

```js
const target = document.querySelector('.target');

function eventWheel(e) {
  // horizontal
  if (e.deltaX != '-0') {
    e.preventDefault();
    // working
  }
  // Vertical
  if (e.deltaY != '-0') {
    e.preventDefault();
    // working
  }
}

target.addEventListener('wheel', eventWheel, { passive: false });
```

Answer (score -1):

I expect that actually no...

But according to [How to detect horizontal scrolling in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076763/how-to-detect-horizontal-scrolling-in-jquery) you may try:

```
var lastScrollLeft = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var documentScrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
    if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
        console.log('scroll x');
        lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft;
    }
});
```

Need to time-it to double check which method is the quickest one ...