# How to detect Horizontal scroll on "onScroll" event in React?

Tags: reactjs

I need to execute a function only when the user is horizontally scrolling. And I need it onScroll event. How to do this in React?

```
<div style={{position: "absolute", width: "50%", height: "50%", overflow: "scroll"}}>
  <table onScroll={...here I need to execute function only on right scroll}>
      ...
  </table>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: Solution

```
const tableRef = useRef(null);

const onScroll = () => { 
  console.log(tableRef.current?.scrollLeft)
 }

<div style={{position: "absolute", width: "50%", height: "50%", overflow: "scroll"}}>
  <table ref={tableRef} onScroll={onScroll}>
      ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to detect horizontal scroll only without triggering a browser reflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112158/is-there-a-way-to-detect-horizontal-scroll-only-without-triggering-a-browser-ref)

Comment: dont forget to wrap it around `useEffect()` onmount, and onunmount (if you are using hooks)

Comment: I usually read and test all possible solutions from Stackoverflow before asking questions. The answers are not working, and are a bit outdated, so that is why I want to check if there has been some improvement on this. @DavidYappeter

Comment: Okay, gimme some minutes to make it in react

Comment: What if i tell you that ref can be used. Is it absolutely necessary for you to use onScroll event?

Comment: What if I tell you that worked @Harry

Comment: Well i never use ref to take a scroll value before, but what variable did you take out from `ref.current.[variable?]`, I only know that there is `offset` value from `ref`, but never heard of scroll value. @Harry

Comment: @DavidYappeter We can access anything related to scroll from ref. Properties like ```offsetTop```, ```offsetLeft```, ```scrollLeft```, ```scrollTop```, ```scrollHeight```, ```scrollWidth```, ```clientHeight```, ```clientWidth```. The signature is the same for all like: ```ref.current.scrollTop```. Recently I developed auto-scroll feature with speed parameter for multiple tables in one page using single ref. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Ahh okay, that give me an idea

Comment: Wait, so how you listen to the scroll change? I try something like this `useEffect(() => {}, [refer.current.scrollLeft])`, but that is not possible because `current` is null before it is attached to the component. @Harry

Comment: I have updated my question with working solution

Comment: @DavidYappeter Basically I used ```refer.current.scrollBy({top: 0, left: 100px})``` and run it with setInterval inside useEffect in all the directions one by one by checking if it reached vertical end or horizontal end and then recursively call the function again. I further optimised it with scroll speed which ```scrollBy``` doesn't provide. It was a complex requirement and i did with ref easily. I'd be happy to help elsewhere since I can't explain much in comments here.

Comment: @DavidYappeter Basically I used ```refer.current.scrollBy({top: 0, left: 100px})``` and run it with setInterval inside useEffect in all the directions one by one by checking if it reached vertical end or horizontal end and then recursively call the function again. I further optimised it with scroll speed which ```scrollBy``` doesn't provide. It was a complex requirement and i did with ref easily. I'd be happy to help elsewhere since I can't explain much in comments here.

Comment: Okay, I understand the setInterval one.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-sound-rkokr9

You can check the console, it only printout value on horizontal scroll.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    var ticking = false;
    var lastScrollLeft = 0;

    const onScroll = () => {
      if (!ticking) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
          var documentScrollLeft = window.scrollX;
          if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
            console.log(
              "only scroll x, lastScroll: ",
              lastScrollLeft,
              " documentScrollNow",
              documentScrollLeft
            );
            lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft;
          }

          ticking = false;
        });
        ticking = true;
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ width: "300vw", height: "150vh" }}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

From the related article, I change `window.scrollLeft` to `window.scrollX`, this has some issue. `scrollLeft` is for IE.

Add `window.addEventListener()` inside useEffect so it doesn't get runned again every state changed, and onunmount which is `return () => {}` callback, we remove the eventlistener.

// UPDATE

Solution for your table onScroll

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-silence-xuwfl2

maybe something like this.

Comment: Maybe I confused you with the text, so I added a small code-snippet. I think there should be a more elegant solution without accessing Window

Comment: @AmelAmcëMuminovic update the solution, still using onScroll, but on the component instead